# Getting "error: invalid regular expression"

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this code where I'd like to replace all single backslashes with 2 backslashes, for example: \ ---> \\ I tried to do this by the following code:

```
string = string.replace(new RegExp("\\", "g"), "\\\\");
```

But apparently this doesn't work because I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //: \ at end of pattern

Any idea why?

Comment: MOAR BACKSLASHES! That is, a single, unpaired backslash is invalid in regexps. It must be paired with a second one. Catering escaping in strings you need four (yes, four) backslashes to make it work: `"\\\\"`

Comment: By the way: That's one of the reasons, why Python has the "raw" string notation: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague

Comment: @Boldewyn: Right, and it's also one of the reasons that JavaScript has a regular expression literal .

Comment: @davcs86 `/` delimiter is only for regex literals, which OP's code is not using (he's creating a `RegExp` object, so no regex delimiter is used)

Comment: @Boldewyn: The answer section is down there: ↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yep, thanks ☺! I started to notice myself, that I tend to do quick comments more often now than full-fledged answers. I should change that back…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `\` is a escape character for regular expressions, and also for javascript strings. This means that the javascript string `"\\"` will produce the following content :`\`. But that single `\` is a escape character for the regex, and when the regex compiler finds it, he thinks: "nice, i have to escape the next character"... but, there is no next character. So the correct regex pattern should be `\\`. That, when escaped in a javascript script is `"\\\\"`.

So you should use:

```
string = string.replace(new RegExp("\\\\", "g"), "\\\\");
```

as an alternative, and to avoid the javascript string escape, you can use a literal regex:

```
string = string.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```

Comment: Well, it was _not_ humourous, but rather deeply hurtful and offensive. Keep your audience in mind and remember that this is a professional Q&A not the school playground. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You escaped the backslash for JavaScript's string literal purposes, but you did not escape it for the regex engine's purposes. Remember, you are dealing with layers of technology here.

So:

```
string = string.replace(new RegExp("\\\\", "g"), "\\\\");
```

Or, much better:

```
string = string.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```